# Typescript global variable with default value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create global variable with default value.
I added the variable in Customer.d.ts

```
 export {}
 declare global {

   var test1: keyvalue[] = [{key: 1, value: 'test'},{key: 2, value: 'test2'}]

   interface keyvalue {
       key: number,
       value: string
    }
 }
```

then I'm trying to access the test1 variable on there file but i'm not getting any value the error says test1 is not define.

any thoughts?

any to get the value of test1 variable

Answer (score 0):

All that a `.d.ts` does is declare the existence and types of variables. It is not ran as code, so you cannot define variables with values. You need to that in your `.js` file.

Since you're using `global`, I'm assuming this is in a node environment. Somewhere in your `.js` files, you need to add:

```js
global.test1 = [{key: 1, value: 'test'},{key: 2, value: 'test2'}]
```

Either have that at the top of your main file, or have it inside of an import before you try to use it.

If this is for the browser, replace `global` with `window`.